# why the velocity in some constrained motion is greater than the provided velocities?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, kinematics, energy-conservation

[image: hcv vol 1]

Suppose the string provided is inextensible and massless.
The velocity of $C$ is $2$ m/s and the angle theta is $37^\circ$ then we get the velocity of ring $A$ to be $v = 2/ \cos37^\circ$ i.e. $10/4$.
I wish to ask that how it is possible for ring to acquire a velocity greater than that provided? How is this possible?

Comment: why it would be $\frac 2{\cos 37^o}$ rather than $2\cos37^o$?

Comment: That exactly is my question...

Comment: By power method, -Tv+TVacos(37})=0, so Va=V/cos(37)

Answer (score 1):

[image: Illustration]

Let the velocity of the ring be $v_r$. Let $AA'=v_rdt$. Let $A'H$ be perpendicular with $AB$. Hence $AH=vdt$. Therefore $(\cos A)v_rdt=vdt$. Therefore $v_r=\frac v {\cos A}$.

Comment: Can you explain why would AH be equal to vdt please.

Comment: Intuitively, You would have vdt = AB-A'B and since $\angle B$ is very small BH=A'B. Strictly, you can use calculus to prove this